# Impossible to send mail to microsoft (hotmail, live ...)

Tags: postfix, smtp

I cannot send mail to hotmail with my postfix server. I can send and receive mail from gmail and others, but not hotmail.

I made an "Authentication Report" on `auth-results@verifier.port25.com`:

```
==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         neutral
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham

==========================================================
Details:
==========================================================

HELO hostname:  bart.localdomain
Source IP:      62.210.240.55
mail-from:      contact@dimsolution.com

----------------------------------------------------------
SPF check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass 
ID(s) verified: smtp.mailfrom=contact@dimsolution.com
DNS record(s):
    dimsolution.com. SPF (no records)
    dimsolution.com. 3522 IN TXT "1|www.dimsolution.com"
    dimsolution.com. 3522 IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:62.210.240.55 -all"
    dimsolution.com. 3522 IN A 62.210.240.55

----------------------------------------------------------
DomainKeys check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         neutral (message not signed)
ID(s) verified: header.From=contact@dimsolution.com
DNS record(s):

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         neutral (message not signed)
ID(s) verified: 

NOTE: DKIM checking has been performed based on the latest DKIM specs
(RFC 4871 or draft-ietf-dkim-base-10) and verification may fail for
older versions.  If you are using Port25's PowerMTA, you need to use
version 3.2r11 or later to get a compatible version of DKIM.

----------------------------------------------------------
Sender-ID check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass 
ID(s) verified: header.From=contact@dimsolution.com
DNS record(s):
    dimsolution.com. SPF (no records)
    dimsolution.com. 3522 IN TXT "1|www.dimsolution.com"
    dimsolution.com. 3522 IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:62.210.240.55 -all"
    dimsolution.com. 3522 IN A 62.210.240.55

----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin v3.3.1 (2010-03-16)

Result:         ham  (-0.2 points, 5.0 required)

 pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
-1.9 BAYES_00               BODY: Bayes spam probability is 0 to 1%
                            [score: 0.0000]
 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
 1.7 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_08     BODY: HTML: images with 400-800 bytes of words

==========================================================
Explanation of the possible results (from RFC 5451)
==========================================================

SPF and Sender-ID Results
=========================

"none"
      No policy records were published at the sender's DNS domain.

"neutral"
      The sender's ADMD has asserted that it cannot or does not
      want to assert whether or not the sending IP address is authorized
      to send mail using the sender's DNS domain.

"pass"
      The client is authorized by the sender's ADMD to inject or
      relay mail on behalf of the sender's DNS domain.

"policy"
     The client is authorized to inject or relay mail on behalf
      of the sender's DNS domain according to the authentication
      method's algorithm, but local policy dictates that the result is
      unacceptable.

"fail"
      This client is explicitly not authorized to inject or
      relay mail using the sender's DNS domain.

"softfail"
      The sender's ADMD believes the client was not authorized
      to inject or relay mail using the sender's DNS domain, but is
      unwilling to make a strong assertion to that effect.

"temperror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is likely transient in nature, such as a temporary inability to
      retrieve a policy record from DNS.  A later attempt may produce a
      final result.

"permerror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is unrecoverable, such as a required header field being absent or
      a syntax error in a retrieved DNS TXT record.  A later attempt is
      unlikely to produce a final result.


DKIM and DomainKeys Results
===========================

"none"
      The message was not signed.

"pass"
      The message was signed, the signature or signatures were
      acceptable to the verifier, and the signature(s) passed
      verification tests.

"fail"
      The message was signed and the signature or signatures were
      acceptable to the verifier, but they failed the verification
      test(s).

"policy"
      The message was signed but the signature or signatures were
      not acceptable to the verifier.

"neutral"
      The message was signed but the signature or signatures
      contained syntax errors or were not otherwise able to be
      processed.  This result SHOULD also be used for other
      failures not covered elsewhere in this list.

"temperror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is likely transient in nature, such as a temporary inability
      to retrieve a public key.  A later attempt may produce a
      final result.

"permerror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is unrecoverable, such as a required header field being
      absent. A later attempt is unlikely to produce a final result.


==========================================================
Original Email
==========================================================

Return-Path: <contact@dimsolution.com>
Received: from bart.localdomain (62.210.240.55) by verifier.port25.com id hfnbc211u9cn for <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>; Thu, 22 May 2014 06:51:45 -0400 (envelope-from <contact@dimsolution.com>)
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=contact@dimsolution.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; domainkeys=neutral (message not signed) header.From=contact@dimsolution.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; dkim=neutral (message not signed)
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; sender-id=pass header.From=contact@dimsolution.com
Received: by bart.localdomain (Postfix, from userid 33)
    id 58E2FF401AB; Thu, 22 May 2014 12:51:45 +0200 (CEST)
To: check-auth@verifier.port25.com
Subject: fsdfg
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 501:rcube.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="=_b148f0ac1d5edc2ff6cb8772d93c5c22"
Date: Thu, 22 May 2014 12:51:45 +0200
From: Agence web Dim'Solution <contact@dimsolution.com>
Organization: Dim'Solution
Message-ID: <1e17adc6630c90ded8b6bf2b80596ac4@dimsolution.com>
X-Sender: contact@dimsolution.com
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/1.0.0

--=_b148f0ac1d5edc2ff6cb8772d93c5c22
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

Error from /var/log/mail.log:

```
May 18 17:50:32 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12608]: D1487F40CB0: lost connection with mx4.hotmail.com[65.55.92.152] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:32 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12607]: 766E8F40C92: lost connection with mx4.hotmail.com[207.46.8.199] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:32 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12610]: E4F64F40AB5: lost connection with mx3.hotmail.com[207.46.8.199] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:32 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12612]: 2BBBAF40AB4: lost connection with mx4.hotmail.com[65.55.33.119] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:33 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12608]: D1487F40CB0: lost connection with mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.168] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:33 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12610]: E4F64F40AB5: lost connection with mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.92.136] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:33 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12607]: 766E8F40C92: lost connection with mx4.hotmail.com[65.55.37.104] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:33 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12612]: 2BBBAF40AB4: lost connection with mx3.hotmail.com[207.46.8.167] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:33 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12608]: D1487F40CB0: lost connection with mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.92.168] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:33 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12610]: E4F64F40AB5: lost connection with mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.92.168] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:33 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12607]: 766E8F40C92: lost connection with mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.152] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:33 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12612]: 2BBBAF40AB4: lost connection with mx3.hotmail.com[65.55.92.136] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:34 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12608]: D1487F40CB0: lost connection with mx3.hotmail.com[65.54.188.94] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:34 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12607]: 766E8F40C92: lost connection with mx3.hotmail.com[65.55.92.168] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:34 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12610]: E4F64F40AB5: lost connection with mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.37.88] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:34 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12612]: 2BBBAF40AB4: lost connection with mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.37.104] while performing the HELO handshake
May 18 17:50:34 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12608]: D1487F40CB0: to=<jeftiy@hotmail.fr>, relay=mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184]:25, delay=21407, delays=21405/0.05/2/0, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184] while performing the HELO handshake)
May 18 17:50:34 sd-45290 postfix/smtp[12610]: E4F64F40AB5: to=<daisy11@hotmail.fr>, relay=mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.136]:25, delay=332155, delays=332152/0.06/2.2/0, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.136] while performing the HELO handshake)
```

What could be wrong?